# How can I access different Anaconda environment from Pycharm (on Windows 10)

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed anaconda with python 3.5, and created a new environment with Python 2.7 (on windows 10).

I can easily change the Anaconda environment with the command line tool. However in Pycharm, when I try to change the Python interpreter, I can only see the Anaconda Python 3.5 version.

Is there a easy way to select the Anaconda environment from Pycharm?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In PyCharm you can add how many interpreter you want. You have to go in

```
Settings->Project->Project Interpreter
```

Here, you should see the current interpreter. 
At the top of the window, there is a list which contains all local interpreters. 
If you find it in the list select it, otherwise, in the right corner of the window, there is a `settings` icon; press it and press on `Add local`. 
After this navigate in your computer and select the directory that contains the Anaconda env.

**edit**
As PatriceG suggested in comments, if you already have an Anaconda environment but you don't know where is it or you don't remember, you can check the current position using the following command:

```
conda info --envs
```

Then, you should be able to find and select it.

Now, you have to add the anconda env to your local interpreter, so you are able to use it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, it worked! With the command line "conda info --envs", I found where is the binary for the new python version (in " C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py27\"). I was able to load it with the "Add local" command in Pycharm. Great!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot ^^

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: you have to select the python.exe file in the env folder.

Comment: suggest to merge get conda env command "conda info --envs" from PatriceG's comment to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Setting** then **Project Interpreter** Click on Setting icon which will lead to browse folder, Choose **Add Local** then on left side of page, click on **system Interpreter** then Press OK and Apply.